# Failed in generating Tesseract traineddata

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract v5.0.1.20220118 on Windows 10, training a font only have letter "P" and "Q".

When I get to the step

```
mftraining -F font_properties.txt -U unicharset -O normal.unicharset pq.normal.exp0.tr
```

The `pffmtable` file is not generated.

And when I run code `cntraining pq.normal.exp0.tr`

It shows me

```
Reading pq.normal.exp0.tr ...
Clustering ...
N == sizeof(Cluster->Mean):Error:Assert failed:in file ../../../src/classify/cluster.cpp, line 2526
```

Why it goes wrong? How can I fix it?

I only have `inttemp` and `shapetable` generated, but the tutorial says there will be four files include `shapetable`, `inttemp`, `pffmtable` and `normproto`, I wonder that maybe is beacuse of the font only have letter "P" and "Q", but I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the docs:

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/#training-for-tesseract-5

Use the right tools:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesstrain

Comment: training for tesseract5 is different from 4 or earlier version ?

Comment: I change my Tesseract version and solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Training tool you refer was used for tesseract 3.x version (a.k.a. legacy engine). 4.x and above use LSTM engine.